# In a constructor, find which class created the object?

Tags: java, constructor

Here's what I'm trying to do:

In my code, I have sets of classes that create objects of other classes. What I am trying to do is, in the constructor of the class that's constructor gets called, find the class which called the constructor in the first place.

For example:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }

}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(){
    //somehow find the class where I came from :(
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there's no way of doing that without either explicitly passing a value to the constructor or constructing a stack trace - which may be inaccurate due to JIT inlining.

Comment: Noo! This design sounds like a nightmare :|

Comment: Please be aware that doing this is a huge violation of object oriented principles. If nothing else it will force you to rewrite the class' constructor if you ever want to construct the class from a different location. Get the calling class to pass in an argument to say what it wants the constructor to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().runMe();
    }

    public void runMe() {
        new Test(this.getClass());
    }
}

class Test {
    public Test(Class clazz) {
        System.out.println("I was invoked from '" + clazz.getCanonicalName() + "' class.");
    }
}
```

Prints:

> I was invoked from 'Main' class.

Comment: I tried calling for a class in the constructor, but it gave me an 'invalid type' error on it.

Comment: You want to say that you copied my code, run it, but it does not work?

Comment: +1 This is the only reliable way to do it.

Comment: OH! Nevermind, I see it now, I wasn't capitalizing the 'C' in 'class', so it gave me the error. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that you can't pass in the Class object of your caller**: Other than the fact that the very need for this implies a rather obnoxious design, then, the only way you can do this is to construct an exception and inspecting the last stack trace element in it:

```
Exception e = new Exception();
StackTraceElement[] elements = e.getStackTrace();
```

The first element in the array is what you're looking for.

(Updated following a comment) This won't work consistently in JITted environments.

Comment: Works great, thanks! And yes, I know my design is flawed :)

Comment: @cyentw I know it works. But please, don't do this.

Comment: I actually use this when initialising loggers - I think this is actually a good use case for it (calling `Logger.getLogger()` from each class is much less prone to error than manually specifying class names in each one, since inevitably one will get copied over with the wrong name!)

Comment: @berry120 so perhaps people should be educated to not copy & paste code.

Comment: @berry120 plus, you're setting yourself up for a failure due to JIT. Unlikely, but still theoretically possible.

Comment: @Isaac Sure, people *shouldn't* copy and paste code, but theory and practice differ on that front! I'm pretty sure the JIT likelihood is much less than the likelihood of someone leaving a bogus class name somewhere. Accept it's not perfect though, should probably look at changing it at some point...

Comment: @berry120 how about suggesting that class-level logging becomes a standard, built-in operation of `java.lang.Object`? :-)

Comment: @Isaac Yes, that would be very nice. Again though, in practice I very much doubt that will happen!